# regex string length validaiton

Tags: regex, r

In R, I need to remove string that exceeds the length of 7 characters, from a column in a data frame.
My code is,

```
memos.to <- as.data.frame(apply(memos.to,2,function(x)gsub('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$/', NA ,x)))
```

and it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong here?

Comment: Please give an example and look at the `nchar` function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just check the string length.
Don't know R lang, but all things being equal, if it conforms to the minimal modern regex's

One of these should match as far as regex is concerned

`/.{8,}/` using Dot-all modifier as external flag
or
`/(?s).{8,}/`
or
`/[\S\s]{8,}/` if Dot-all not available

if you are only considering `[a-zA-Z0-9]` chars
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/`